# Accessing MathematicaScript over ssh/network

Tags: scripting, grid-layouts, networking

Here is the conundrum I am faced with. I have two computer. One with Mathematica (and hence `MathematicaScript`) but generally *poor* resources. The other without Mathematica but *excellent* resources (good amount of disk space, RAM, processor power).

Since the local IT department who are the computer overlords here will take forever to get Mathematica installed on the better of the two machines...

> Is there a way I could modify my Mathematica script's shebang to
>   access `MathematicaScript` over an ssh connection? 
>   So in essence, am I trying to run Mathematica over a network? Is that > possible without a regular gridMathematica license?

The shebang, right now, looks like. I'd like to incorporate an ssh access functionality to it.

```
!#/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but can't you execute `ssh poor.machine -c scriptname`?

Comment: @rcollyer Can I do that? Is that a unix thing that I am unaware of? I am certain I can log in to the poor.machine but as I lack admin rights, I am unsure I can pass my password through ssh.

Comment: @rcollyer Do you mean run the script on the `poor.machine`? that won't help as it doesn't have the resources necessary. It quite soon throttles the cpu as a result of overheating.

Comment: Yes, I do. Do you mean to run the kernel on `good.machine` even though it is installed on `poor.machine`?

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, I'd like to run the kernel on the `good.machine` although it is installed in the `poor.machine`

Comment: @rcollyer It would seem I am looking for *mathematica scripts via remote kernel*

Comment: Does the good machine have sshfs installed? Then you *might* be able to remote-mount the Mathematica directory as user and execute it from there. However I don't know if Mathematica depends on hardcoded information on where it is installed (since you probably don't have the necessary rights to mount it on the good machine onto the installation path it sits at on the poor machine, it will appear in a different place on the good machine). Also, whether it works may depend on other factors, e.g. if the licensing server doesn't accept requests from the good machine, you're out of luck.

Comment: @drN: what you are actually asking is to run Mathematica on good.machine without having it installed there. As celtschk pointed out that might be possible -- but I'm quite sure that any of those possibilities will a) be harder to set up than convincing your IT department to do their job, b)  require admissions on good.machine which you don't have if your IT department did their job and c) most probably violate the terms of your license...

Comment: @celtschk Yes, sshfs is available on both machines. Thanks for your detailed comment.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Food for thought, eh? `:P`

Comment: @drN Are you still online? Can you meet me in chat? [Link to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)

Comment: @halirutan I got to the chat a little too late! `:(`